# Javascript problem with logical operations and greater than

Tags: javascript

Hello I am learning JavaScript and I have a question, I have made simple algorithm to check "if something". My question is about this line `if(dolphins && koalas > minimumScore)`. It seems to me illogical, but it works in a way I want. Because in beginning I wanted to check if dolphins or koalas > minimumScore (So I used `||`). But when I set both teams to value under 100 it kept going to the next `if` block and `else if` but not to else statement. So I had to use && and it works, it goes to the else if both teams are under 100 and goes to the next 'if' when at least one team is higher than 100.

```
let dolphins = 11;
let koalas = 11
const minimumScore = 100

if(dolphins && koalas > minimumScore){
    if(koalas > dolphins){
        console.log(`Koalas won! {$koalas}`)
    } else if(koalas===dolphins){
        console.log('draw')
    } else {
        console.log('dolphins won!')
    }
} else{
    console.log('no team won')
}
```

Comment: The line says: if `dolphins` *are truthy*, and `koalas` are over `minimumScore`… You need `if (dolphins > minimumScore || koalas > minimumScore)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So `(dolphins && koalas > minimumScore)` is not checking if dolphins is greater than minimumScore and koalas is greater than minimum score. It is checking if dolphins is "truthy" and if koalas is greater than minimumScore. if you want to check that one or the other are greater than minimum score you must write.

```
(dolphins > minimumScore || koalas > minimumScore)
```

more about truthy values
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Answer (score 0):

that if is not written like this, it is usually written like this:

```
if (koalas > mininumScore && dolphins > mininumScore)
```